# How does Angular Bootstrap $modal animate out?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm not using any bootstrap styles. I'm customizing everything completely. It's fairly straight forward to animate in, because the `$modal` uses `.fade.in`. I was able to override those styles and it works great. But how does the modal animate out? I see no classes being applied or removed. It is simply removed from the DOM instantly.

**How can I customize the `animate out` event?** Does it use CSS classes? Does it use JS?

It seems this question is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595622/how-to-slideout-a-bootstrap-modal-in-angular. Unfortunately there is not a solution.

Comment: There are a bunch of css that does the animation ex:- `.modal.fade .modal-dialog`, `.modal.in .modal-dialog` `.fade.in`. You can override them.. Animate out happens when the class is removed and the transition is applied.. If you inspect the modal dialog it has an ng-class `ng-class="{in: animate}` so animate is toggled inorder for animation to happen. Inorder to give enough time for animation modal is remove from the DOM only in a $timeout

Comment: Or u can on popup close: change ng-class and dissmiss popup in $timeout. Not best way thow.

Comment: I think it should work, can you provide an example demo on this, possibly on a jsbin.

Comment: Ah, you are correct @PSL. It was a simple CSS change that fixed it. Thanks