# Need to add fade to disappearance of a modal animation in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am making a modal appear, and then disappear with a setinterval, but this happens too abrupt. How can I make my modal disappear with an effect similar to ('fade') of jquery or just to slow down the animation

http://fiddle.jshell.net/f1v8pcqs/

```
var modalInstance = null;
var modalScope = $scope.$new();
     modalInstance = $modal.open({
         templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
         scope: modalScope
     });

setInterval(function(){ modalInstance.dismiss(); }, 3000);
```

Comment: Look at this it may give you an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408682/how-does-angular-bootstrap-modal-animate-out and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617610/angular-ui-bootstrap-modal